# Does drush support everything I can do with web admin interface?

Tags: drush

I have just learned about Drush. Its great command-line tool. With two words, I can update drupal code within seconds.

I want to know whether I can do everything I do with web admin interface or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. That's not possible.

Every command needs to be explicitly provided to Drush. Many contrib modules now come with integrated drush commands, for example Devel generate, Features, Views, XML Sitemap and so on.

To see the list of commands that are available to you, call `drush help`. You can get detailed help on each command with `drush help <command>`.

Comment: See also http://drush.org/resources for a list of some of the other Drush extensions that are available.